# Java: Restrict the mouse movement to vertical

Tags: java, swing

Is there a way to restrict the mouse movement to vertical? I am currently developing a program when user dragging mouse pointer to the left or right in specific rectangle shape cursor can't move but up and down movements should work.

Comment: You  can't restrict the mouse movement, but you can ignore the changes in X (left or right), and just use the changes in Y (up or down).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try like this,f is reference to a Jframe but here the X co-ordinate is fixed.

```
final Robot r=new Robot();
f.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionListener(){
        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {

              r.mouseMove(20, e.getY());
        }
    });
```